# Format a date on Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I need a bit of help as my Java script knowledge is poor. I've dealt mainly with HTML and PHP in the past. I need to make a date form that adds a number to a specified date, which I've had some help with and it works. The only think I need to change is the format the date comes out in. At the moment it's out put in the format 'Fri, 02 Jan 2015 00:00:00 GMT' Where as I would quite like it to come out at 02/01/2015

Thanks in advance for your help. I've searched this over and over, but can't find anything that works with my code!

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myStartDate" value="01/01/2015">
<select id="myDays">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
```

Javascript

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('myStartDate'),
selectElement = document.getElementById('myDays'),
resultElement = document.getElementById('myResult');

function updateResultElement() {
var parts = inputElement.value.split('/'),
    dateObject;

parts[1] -= 1;
parts.reverse();
dateObject = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(undefined, parts));
dateObject.setUTCDate(dateObject.getUTCDate() + Number(selectElement.value));
resultElement.textContent = dateObject.toUTCString();
}

inputElement.addEventListener('change', updateResultElement, false);
selectElement.addEventListener('change', updateResultElement, false);
updateResultElement();
```

Comment: Use the `Date.*` methods here to create the format you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2

Comment: If you're open to using a third party lib, I would definitely recommend momentJS for dealing with dates in JavaScript - very easy to use and a well documented API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

I'd use the [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library, which has extensive support for date and time formatting.

You should be able to use it in your program as follows:

```
dateObject = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(undefined, parts));
dateObject.setUTCDate(dateObject.getUTCDate() + Number(selectElement.value));
resultElement.textContent = moment(dateObject).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```